# Android: Failed to create SD card

Tags: android, macos, bash, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hard time installing ia32-lib on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223192/hard-time-installing-ia32-lib-on-mac-osx)

I'm trying to create a new virtual device from the ADT in Eclipse running on my Leopard OSX with a 64bit Java 6, when it comes to create the sd card from the SDK manager i get

```
[2012-08-31 21:10:17 - SDK Manager] Failed to create the SD card.
```

[2012-08-31 21:10:17 - SDK Manager] Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.

I have investigated a bit around and found that the problem was the permissions on the files within the tools directory in the SDK dir, so i changed it to full permissions to all files rwxrwxrwx, restarted Eclipse the problem persisted, so i have investigated again and found that because Android runs on a 32 bit JDK, since i have a 64-bit installed i have to install the ia32-libs
, the problem now is this, when i run the command 'sudo apt-get install ia32-libs', the shell responds: sudo: apt-get: command not found

indeed under 'man apt' i cant find the 'get' option.
Do you have any advice on how i can install this lib?

Thank you all,

Comment: Apparenlty apt-get is not installed by default on mac osx's distribution

Comment: Added the package by installing Fink, still when trying to install i get E: Couldn't find package ia32-libs

Comment: The same as I'm saying in your other thread: [Hard time installing ia32-lib on mac osx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223192/hard-time-installing-ia32-lib-on-mac-osx).  You should be able to use the Android SDK (including create a virtual SD card) on Mac OSX *without* needing "ia32-libs".  Look here, for example: http://www.buzztouch.com/files/howtos/Setting_Up_Your_Android_Development_Environment_For_MacOSX_v1.0.pdf

Comment: Hi, thank you for the pdf, actually i already did all what is explained in that guideline except from downloading and installing the Google API, which i just did but the problem persists, i can only use the emulator if i select a file instead of the SD card option from the AVD tool